# why admin grid edit view not rendering with data in magento 2,It is rendering title but not edit grid....?

Tags: magento2, grid

> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Inkind\Navdata\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Edit.php

```
<?php
namespace Inkind\Navdata\Block\Adminhtml\Post;
class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('navdata_post')->getId()) {
            return __("Edit Post '%1'", $this->escapeHtml($this->_coreRegistry->registry('navdata_post')->getTitle()));
        } else {
            return __('New Post');
        }
    }
    /**
     * Check permission for passed action
     *
     * @param string $resourceId
     * @return bool
     */

}
```

> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Inkind\Navdata\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Edit\Form.php

```
<?php
namespace Inkind\Navdata\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Edit;
/**
 * Adminhtml blog post edit form
 */
class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Init form
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('post_form');
        $this->setTitle(__('Post Information'));
    }
    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        /** @var \Ashsmith\Blog\Model\Post $model */
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('navdata_post');
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]
        );
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('logs_');
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('General Information'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
        );
        if ($model->getPostId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id']);
        }
        $fieldset->addField(
            'transaction_type',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'title', 'label' => __('Post Title'), 'title' => __('Post Title'), 'required' => true]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'request',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'request',
                'label' => __('Request'),
                'title' => __('Request'),
                'required' => true,
                'class' => 'validate-xml-identifier'
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'response',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'response',
                'label' => __('Response'),
                'title' => __('Response'),
                'required' => true,
                'class' => 'validate-xml-identifier'
            ]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'created_at',
            'date',
            [
                'name' => 'created_at',
                'label' => __('Crated At'),
                'title' => __('Crated At'),
                'required' => true,
                'class' => 'validate-xml-identifier'
            ]
        );

        if (!$model->getId()) {
            $model->setData('is_active', '1');
        }

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Inkind\Navdata\view\adminhtml\ui_component\inkind_navdata_post_listing.xml

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">inkind_navdata_post_listing.inkind_navdata_post_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">inkind_navdata_post_listing.inkind_navdata_post_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">spinner_columns</item>
         <!-- <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Post</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>  -->
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="nameOfDataSource">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">inkind_navdata_post_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>


    <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>


    <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>


    <!-- <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>  -->


    <filters name="listing_filters" />


       <!--  <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="inkind_navdata/post/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Post</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction> -->


    <paging name="listing_paging"/>


    <exportButton name="export_button"/>
    </listingToolbar>

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">inkind_navdata_listing.inkind_navdata_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">inkind_navdata_listing.inkind_navdata_listing.inkind_navdata_columns.actions</item>
                         <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="inkind_navdata/post/Edit"/>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="controlVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">inkind_navdata_listing.inkind_navdata_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">inkind_navdata/post/edit</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>

    <columns name="spinner_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="transaction_type">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Transaction Type</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="request">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Request</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="response">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Response</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>


    <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Inkind\Navdata\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PostActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>




</listing>
```

> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Inkind\Navdata\view\adminhtml\layout\inkind_navdata_post_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="inkind_navdata_post_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
          <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Inkind\Navdata\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Edit"
                name="inkind_navdata_post.edit"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Inkind\Navdata\Controller\Adminhtml\Logs.php

```
<?php

namespace Inkind\Navdata\Controller\Adminhtml;

// use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Inkind\Navdata\Model\PostFactory;

 abstract class Logs extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
//class News extends Action
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * Result page factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * News model factory
     *
     * @var \Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory
     */
    protected $_postFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param NewsFactory $newsFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, Registry $coreRegistry,PageFactory $resultPageFactory,PostFactory $postFactory)
    {
       parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
    }

    /**
     * News access rights checking
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Inkind_Navdata::manage_post');
    }
}
```

> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Inkind\Navdata\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Edit.php

```
<?php

namespace Inkind\Navdata\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

use Inkind\Navdata\Controller\Adminhtml\Logs;

class Edit extends Logs
{
   /**
     * @return void
     */
   public function execute()
   {
      $newsId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        /** @var \Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\News $model */
        $model = $this->_postFactory->create();

        if ($newsId) {
            $model->load($newsId);
            if (!$model->getId()) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('This news no longer exists.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
        }

        // Restore previously entered form data from session
        $data = $this->_session->getPostData(true);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }
        $this->_coreRegistry->register('simplenews_news', $model);

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Inkind_Navdata::main_menu');
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Simple News'));

        return $resultPage;
   }
}
```

> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Inkind\Navdata\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Grid.php

```
<?php

namespace Inkind\Navdata\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

use Inkind\Navdata\Controller\Adminhtml\Logs;

class Grid extends Logs
{
   /**
     * @return void
     */
   public function execute()
   {
      return $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
   }
}
```

> ```
> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Inkind\Navdata\Model\Post.php
> ```

```
<?php
namespace Inkind\Navdata\Model;
class Post extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    const CACHE_TAG = 'api_data';

    protected $_cacheTag = 'api_data';

    protected $_eventPrefix = 'api_data';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Inkind\Navdata\Model\ResourceModel\Post');
    }

    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
    }

    public function getDefaultValues()
    {
        $values = [];

        return $values;
    }
}
```

> ```
> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Inkind\Navdata\Model\ResourceModel\Post.php
> ```

```
<?php
namespace Inkind\Navdata\Model\ResourceModel;


class Post extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('api_data', 'id');
    }

}
```

> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Inkind\Navdata\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Inkind\Navdata\Model\ResourceModel\Post;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'inkind_navdata_post_collection';
    protected $_eventObject = 'post_collection';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Inkind\Navdata\Model\Post', 'Inkind\Navdata\Model\ResourceModel\Post');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace with

```
<dataSource name="nameOfDataSource">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">inkind_navdata_post_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
```

with

```
<dataSource name="inkind_navdata_post_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">inkind_navdata_post_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
```

Also [check](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-create-basic-module-admin-grid-part-2/)